# Decide whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{nx}{1+n^4x^2}$ uniformly converges on $[0,\infty)$ or not

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\newcommand{\FUNC}[1]{#1 \frac{nx}{1+n^4x^2}}$

The following problem has bothered me for a very long time. I've been trying to solve this problem for 3 days long - and it feels I tried everything. To conclude - I absolutely need the help of the professionals; And that's why I came here.

I am given with the following function series:

$$S(x)\equiv\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nf_n(x)\equiv\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\FUNC{(-1)^n}$$

My task is to decide whether the series $S(x)$ uniformly converges on $[0,\infty)$, or not.

**Things I tried:**

(1) I tried to use Leibniz's Alternating Series Test. I proved that $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $0$, but the problem is that $f_n(x)$ is not a decreasing sequence - for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $0<x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $f_n(x)$ is *increasing* on $[0,x_0]$, and decreasing on $[x_0,\infty)$. I've noticed that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_0=0$, but that doesn't help - since it would never actually reach $0$ (that would only help to prove that the series uniformly converges on $[c,\infty)$ when $c>0$).

(2) I tried to use Weierstrass's M Test. I found that $f_n(x)\leq\frac{1}{2n}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but that of course won't help (since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}$ diverges). The *huge* problem using the M test is that $\frac{1}{2n}$ is actually a *tight* bound.

(3) I proved that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\FUNC{}$ uniformly converges on $[c,\infty)$ when $c>0$, but does *not* uniformly converges on $[0,\infty)$. That wasn't very helpful, since $S(x)$ might converges conditionally.

(4) Defining:

$$S_m(x)\equiv\sum_{n=1}^{m}\FUNC{(-1)^n}$$

It is sufficient to show that:

$$(*) \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\sup_{[0,\infty)}\left|S_m(x)-S(x)\right|\right)\equiv\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\sup_{[0,\infty)}\left|\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\FUNC{(-1)^n}\right|\right)=0$$

in order to prove the series uniformly converges on $[0,\infty).$ Looks impossible and complicated - yet I was eager to try that too. But to no avail.

I will say that my intuition is that the series *does* uniformly converge on $[0,\infty)$, and that is because I used graphic calculators, and found that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$\sup_{[0,\infty)}\left|\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\FUNC{(-1)^n}\right|\leq\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

And since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, we can say that its limit when $m\to\infty$ is $0$, thus proving $(*)$. However - I couldn't prove this inequality. I tried using the triangle inequality, to distinguish between odd and even indices - **nothing** worked.

As you might see - I really need help. Thank you very much!

Comment: The limit doesn't seem to be continuous on $[0,\infty)$ so the convergence isn't uniform (i think)

Comment: @Pedro I did notice that for the sum of $\frac{nx}{1+n^4x^2}$, but I'm not sure you're correct regarding the sum of $(-1)^n\frac{nx}{1+n^4x^2}$

Comment: I forgot about the -1 sorry

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%5B-1%5D%5En+n+x+%2F+%5B1+%2Bn%5E4+x%5E2%5D,+%7Bn,1,Infinity%7D%5D) thinks the series $\sum (-1)^n nx/(1+n^4x^2)$ converges to $C/x$ with $C\approx-0.41$, so the discontinuity at $0$.

Comment: @user10354138 WolframAlpha treats function series as numerical series, thus the convergence you got is actually a pointwise convergence

Comment: @AmitZach but uniform limit has to agree with pointwise limit, and uniform limit of continuous is continuous.

Comment: @user10354138 Whether or not you're right, I'm going to need a solid proof. I have no idea how to prove the series converges to $\frac Cx$. I know that the function series converges to something similar, but that's not enough of course. If you are right, then I'm going to need to know how to show the series does not converge uniformly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following estimate will be useful:

> **Claim.** For any $a, b, x \geq 0$, we have
>
> $$ \left| \frac{bx}{1+b^4x^2} - \frac{ax}{1+a^4x^2} \right| \leq \frac{3x|b-a|}{1+\min\{a,b\}^4x^2}. $$

*Proof of Claim.* Assume $a < b$ without losing the generality. Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus,

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{bx}{1+b^4x^2} - \frac{ax}{1+a^4x^2}\right|
&\leq \int_{a}^{b} \left|\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \left( \frac{\alpha x}{1+\alpha^4x^2} \right) \right| \, \mathrm{d}\alpha
= \int_{a}^{b} \left| \frac{x(1-3\alpha^4 x^2)}{(1+\alpha^4x^2)^2} \right| \, \mathrm{d}\alpha.
\end{align*}

Now using the triangle inequality, $\left|1-3\alpha^4 x^2\right| \leq 1+3\alpha^4x^2 \leq 3(1+\alpha^4x^2)$, and so, the last integral can be bounded from above by

\begin{align*}
&\leq \int_{a}^{b} \frac{3x}{1+\alpha^4x^2} \, \mathrm{d}\alpha
\leq (b-a) \max_{a \leq \alpha \leq b} \left(\frac{3x}{1+\alpha^4x^2}\right).
\end{align*}

Since the function $\alpha \mapsto 3x/(1+\alpha^4x^2)$ is decreasing in $\alpha$, the maximum is achieved at $\alpha = a$ and the desired inequality follows. ////

Returning to the original problem, note that

$$ \left| f_n(x) - f_{n+1}(x) \right| \leq \frac{3x}{1+n^4x^2} \leq \frac{3}{2n^2}, $$

where the first step is a consequence of the claim and the second step is simply an application of the AM-GM inequality. Therefore, by the Weierstrass M-test, the sum

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} (f_{2k-1}(x) - f_{2k}(x)) $$

converges uniformly on $[0, \infty)$, from which the uniform convergence of $S(x)$ easily follows.

Comment: First of all - You are a true hero. Thank you very much! But - I don't understand the proof of your lemma. Specifically, the transition with the $\leq$. Could you please explain?

Comment: @AmitZach, Glad it helps, and I will add extra steps for clarification!

Comment: @AmitZach that step is the triangle inequality for integrals followed by applying the ordinary triangle inequality to the numerator.

Comment: @SangchulLee I understand it absolutely now. Thank you very much for the detailed and **brilliant** solution!