# How to complete this uniform convergence proof by dividing the real line in appropriate segments?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I tried to solve [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262297/decide-whether-sum-n-1-infty-1n-fracnx1n4x2-uniformly-converge?noredirect=1#comment6708423_3262297). Much of the obvious things to try are there but don't work. After several failed attempts I arrived at this (also failed?) argument:

Let
$$f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^4x^2}$$
The goal is to prove that
$$F_m(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{m}(-1)^nf_n(x)$$
converges uniformly in $[0,\infty)$. I've tried the following:

First of all, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and every $x\in[0,\infty)$ we have $|f_n(x)|<\frac{1}{2n}$

Given $x_0\in[0,\infty)$ and taking $f_n(x_0)$ as a function of $n$ we get that the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ starts to be decrasing when $n^4\ge\frac{1}{3x_0^2}$ or $x_0\ge\frac{1}{n^2\sqrt{3}}$. Now, for $p>q$
$$|F_p(x_0)-F_q(x_0)|=\left|\sum_{n=q+1}^{p}(-1)^nf_n(x_0)\right|$$
and we separate the following cases:

If $x_0\ge\frac{1}{(q+1)^2\sqrt{3}}$ then $\{f_n(x_0)\}_{n\ge q+1}$ is decreasing so we can use "Leinbiz's criterion proof" to get
$$|F_p(x_0)-F_q(x_0)|<\left|f_{q+1}(x_0)\right|<\frac{1}{2(q+1)}$$
If $x_0\le\frac{1}{p^3\sqrt{3}}$ then $x_0<\frac{1}{n^3}$ for every $n\le p$ and we have
$$|F_p(x_0)-F_q(x_0)|=\left|\sum_{n=q+1}^{p}(-1)^nf_n(x_0)\right|<\sum_{n=q+1}^p\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{q}$$
which we can make small.

If $\frac{1}{p^3\sqrt{3}}\le x_0\le\frac{1}{(q+1)^2\sqrt{3}}$ then none of the bounds i came up with tend to zero. Does someone have an idea? If this worked somehow I think it would be a neat thing to try for other problems.

**Edit:** Please note that when I uploaded my question, the original one already had an accepted answer. I'm not looking for a solution of that exercise but rather for some way to complete my line of reasoning. The functions $f_n$ or $F_m$ don't interest me as much as the "dividing the real line" trick and if it works here or in general for alternating sums of functions

Thanks!

Comment: @user10354138 not a duplicate. Hopefully the edit makes it clear

Comment: @user10354138 can you please explain why this question is a duplicate? I think the edit does make clear that I am aking a different question: not asking for a solution which i knew was already in the original post but for a proof idea completely different from the accepted one. If this is not the place to ask such a question (same function but unrelated in nature) where can I post this? Thanks